# Are questions related to running a freelance business on topic?

Tags: discussion

All of the questions I see on this site are related to office jobs in companies.

I work freelance, and I don't have any questions at the moment, but if I ever do is this site appropriate for freelance-related questions? (I hope so, because I love the answers I see here in general - although most of the questions make me thankful that I don't have an office job...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is, *"It depends"*. We have many questions from people who could as well be freelancers (questions about going over time or over budget for a contracted project for a client), which we are more than happy to keep open here:

- [How do I fix my reputation with a client when I fell through for a project?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/)
- [Taking on multiple clients in the same niche - conflict of interest?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/27584/)
- [What is a tactful way to address client's lack of cooperation with a project?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20358/)

These are just examples, but to me these could all be asked by a freelancer and wouldn't make the question any less appropriate for our site.

If your questions are more about the nitty gritty of freelancing in specific, *"How do I create an invoice?"* or *"How should I provide a cost breakdown of a project to a client for evaluation?"* or the like, then [Freelancing.SE](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) (a Stack Exchange Beta site) may be a better place. Just be sure to [read their help first](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Basically, if you want to ask here, I invite you to. The worst that happens is that it gets closed and/or moved to freelancing.se instead. There are many questions that can be on-topic on multiple sites on the network, and that's perfectly okay, so ask wherever you feel most comfortable and it will help us define our scope, and also help you get a better idea of which questions fit where best.

Look forward to reading your questions!

Comment: Hey thanks especially for pointing out freelancing.se; didn't see that one! It seems like that is better for freelance-specific administrative topics, and workplace.se is good for e.g. personal client relations and politics?

Comment: No problem @Jason! We would be more than happy to have your questions here if they are along the lines of our [help/on-topic], but longer-term you may find freelancing a better fit for certain questions. As a larger graduated site, we have more eyes on questions, but the topic of our site means people may approach it from a different perspective than freelancing would. Best of luck wherever you decide to post!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, Jason, is that we may be hesitant to migrate a question to Freelancing SE that was asked here first. If a question gets a lot of highly up voted answers or lots of answers in general, that may overwhelm the small beta site, which doesn't yet have a large community of answerers. This is something you may want to consider. Hope this helps.